# Selenium: How to stop execuing subsequest steps in @Test method after catching an exception using TestNG Listener?

Tags: selenium, testng, webdrivereventlistener

I am working on PageFactory in Page Object Model and TestNG framework for automation. I am using `beforeFindBy` method in `WebDriverEventListener` to listen for the presence of an element. When an element is not present, `NoSuchElementException` is thrown and I catch the exception using `try-catch` block. How to stop executing remaining steps in @Test method. I do not want to use `try-catch` in my @Test method. Any suggestion on changes in my design is most appreciated. Below is my design.

**LoginPage**

```
    public class LoginPage {

        @FindBy(xpath = "//img[@src='/webres_5786257bd7c8a5.72130757/themes/default/images/login/logo.png']")
        WebElement loginLogo;

        public LoginPage(WebDriver driver, ExtentTest test) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
            this.test = test;
        }

        public void verifyLoginPageLogo() throws IOException {
            Assert.assertTrue(loginLogo.isDisplayed());
            test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Logo is displayed", takeScreenshot(driver, test));
        }
}
```

**Listenter**

```
public class CustomListeners extends TestListenerAdapter implements WebDriverEventListener {

    //All Implemented Methods

    public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element " + by + "not found");
        }
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
@Listeners(CustomListeners.class)
public class Test1 extends BaseTestSuite {

    LoginPage lp;
    TabMenu tm;

    @Test(priority = 0, testName = "Verify Login")
    public void login() throws Exception {
        lp = new LoginPage(driver, test);
        tm = new TabMenu(driver, test);
        driver.get(Constants.url);
        lp.verifyLoginPageLogo();  //Element not present here
        lp.setUserName("dmin");
        lp.setPassword("admin");
        lp.clickLoginBtn();
        tm.verifyTabMenu();
        tm.isCurrentTab("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Login `PageObject` ideally should not contain assertion code. That code should be in your test class. Also the `Extent` functionality should also be in the test class and not the `PageObject`.

There is no need for a `testng listener` or a `webdrivereventlistener`. In the PageObject if restructure the verifyLoginPageLogo() method to below -

```
public boolean isLoginPageLogoDisplayed() throws IOException {
            //Write logic to check if element is displayed.    
            //Return false in case of exception etc
        }
```

In the test class do this -

```
Assert.assertTrue(lp.isLoginPageLogoDisplayed());
```

If an `ArrertionError` is thrown the remaining steps are skipped automatically.

ALso look at creating a `BasePageObject` which has utility methods for checking presence, displayed, finding elements etc etc. Just extend this.

Comment: Thanks. 1)My issue gets resolved by moving `Assertion` to Test class. I am not sure why I need to move `ExtentTest` to test class. How it makes an impact. Could you please provide any example? 2) The reason i used `Listeners` is to constantly check for the presence of an element before executing `findElement` statement which is to avoid `NoSuchElementException`. If  this is not required?  why?

Comment: ExtentTest does not belong in pageobject, it gives the class a dual unrelated purpose. A design anti-pattern as now class can be changed because of two separate areas. ExtentTest report creation is unique to a test case but a pageobject may be used by different test cases. ExtentTest belongs in the Test class as it can be managed more effectively using the configuration methods for setting up and tearing down.

Comment: To avoid NoSuchElementException use an ExpectedCondition with WebDriverWait. With your current approach you are slowing down your tests by finding every element twice. If the website requires constant checking for each element you should use an implicit wait. Also again in your current listener implementation you are using the class as testng listener and also as a webdrivereventlistener, the same issue as above will crop up.